# Error on a computed property getter

Tags: ios, swift, computed-properties

I have in an iOS Swift 3 app, the following computed property.

```
var countItems:[Int] {// Count the interesting items.
    var countResult = [Int]()
    for i in 0..<size {
        var count = 0
        for j in i*size..<(i+1)*size {
            if binaryArray?[j] == true {count += 1}
        }
        countResult.append(count)
    }
    return countResult
}
```

It works perfectly 99.9 percent of the time.
But I got a crash with this message:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fc7bff0)
    frame #0: 0x000000018f2d95b8 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_zone_malloc
    frame #1: 0x000000018f2dc56c libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc + 32
    frame #2: 0x0000000100964048 libswiftCore.dylib`swift_slowAlloc + 12
    frame #3: 0x000000010096409c libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_allocObject_ + 28
    frame #4: 0x0000000100f6cd50 libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib`generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Swift._ArrayBuffer<Swift.Double> with Swift._ArrayBuffer<Swift.Double> : Swift._ArrayBufferProtocol in Swift> of (extension in Swift):Swift._ArrayBufferProtocol._forceCreateUniqueMutableBuffer (countForNewBuffer : Swift.Int, minNewCapacity : Swift.Int) -> Swift._ContiguousArrayBuffer<A.Element> with unmangled suffix "_merged" + 84
    frame #5: 0x0000000100f69d5c libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib`generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Swift.String.CharacterView> of Swift.Array._copyToNewBuffer (oldCount : Swift.Int) -> () with unmangled suffix "_merged" + 76
    frame #6: 0x0000000100f655bc libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib`generic specialization <preserving fragile attribute, Swift.UInt64> of Swift.Array.append (A) -> () with unmangled suffix "_merged" + 124
  * frame #7: 0x0000000100103078 MyApp`TheClass.countItems.getter(self=MyApp.TheClass @ 0x000000016fc7c260) at TheClass.swift:31
    frame #8: 0x0000000100138354 MyApp`TheClass.callingFunction(self=0x000000010201d930) -> Bool at TheClass.swift:2343
```

I wonder if there is a problem in the computed property itself (which Ido not see) or if something must go wrong outside.
If anyone has a clue, I will be very glad.
Thanks in advance for any relevant tip.

For reference, here is another crash with a shorter message:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fc27fb0)
    frame #0: 0x00000001001567bc MyApp`TheClass.countItems.getter(self=MyApp.TheClass @ 0x000000016fc27fb0) at TheClass.swift:0
  * frame #1: 0x000000010018c2e4 MyApp`TheClass.callingFunction(self=0x000000010200c730) -> Bool at TheClass.swift:2348
```

Comment: `for j in i*size..<(i+1)*size` what is this for?

Comment: May be you are trying to access an element outside of the array in this line:  if binaryArray?[j] == true {count += 1}

Comment: What can I say? It is here simply because I need it to compute what I want, namely "count"; which is then added to the "countResult" array as you can see.

Comment: If I was trying to access an element outside of the array, the computation would not be made a zillion times before crashing. Because I always access the same elements. binaryArray is built once and only once. Only the values inside may change.

Answer (score 0):

please try to do work in background thread as you seems doing all your digit procession on main thread which is not good.

either you can make a function which returns array of Integer Items. which will process array in background thread.

As I do not know what is **binaryArray** variable. you can pass in if you need it.

**SWIFT 3.0 :**

```
func countItems(_ size : Int, completion: ([Int])) {
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    queue.async {
        var countResult = [Int]()
        for i in 0..<size {
            var count = 0
            for j in i*size..<(i+1)*size {
                if self.binaryArray?[j] == true {count += 1}
            }
            countResult.append(count)
        }
        completion(countResult) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally a good idea for heavy computations, but I don't think it will solve his problem :(

Comment: Also: when returning the `countResult` array (i.e., calling `completion`) might be wiser to do it in the `DispatchQueue.main` queue to be safe.

Comment: Yes. You can call completion block through main queue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. But it was finally a problem outside of this property computation.

Comment: Hi @Michel, what was the problem outside of this property computation?

Comment: It is a while ago and I do not clearly remember. But when I realized my mistake I know it was not really connected to the question. There was no problem with the computed property.

Answer (score 0):

The first stack trace is clearly inside the `Array.append` method, with a `malloc` call at the top. As such, you might be hitting an internal bug in Swift `Array` implementation, probably on its dynamic memory management code.

Assuming this is true, try allocating the necessary array capacity at *once*, before starting your algorithm:

```
var countResult = [Int]()
countResult.reserveCapacity(size)
```

> If you are adding a known number of elements to an array, use `reserveCapacity` to avoid multiple reallocations. This method ensures that the array has unique, mutable, contiguous storage, with space allocated for at least the requested number of elements.

As a bonus, you might also get a nice performance boost for large values of `size` :)